# Question regarding the distribution of $aW(t)-W(s)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppoe that $W(t)$ is a Brownian Motion. I now that if $t \geq s \geq 0$, then
$W(t)-W(s)$ is $N(0,t-s)$. Now, suppose that $a \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, then how is distributed $$aW(t)-W(s)?$$ I tried to find in the literature about distributions, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Write this as $$aW(t)-W(s)=a(W(t)-W(s))+(a-1)W(s)$$ and use the independence of $W(t)-W(s)$ and $W(s)$ to conclude.

Comment: I know that if $X$ and $Y$ they are independent with $N(0,t)$ an $N(0,s)$, then $Z = X + Y$ is $N(0,t+s)$. I am struggling on how to include the terms $a$ and $(a-1)$ in the distribution.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682842/scaling-the-normal-distribution) might be helpful in that case.

Comment: Well, another basic fact, probably mentioned on the WP page as well, is that if $X$ is normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $aX+b$ is normal $N(\ldots,\ldots)$.

Comment: So $a(W(t)-W(s))+(a-1)W(s)$ would be distributed as $N(0,a^2(t-s)+(1-a)^2s)$

Comment: Indeed it is. $ $